Maximise Arbitrary Utility Subject to Budget Constraint
Suppose we have a general maximization problem of the form:
$$\max_{q_1,q_2} U(q_1,q_2) \text{ subject to } p_1 q_1 + p_2 q_2 = y$$
Suppose I allow $U$ to be concave, increasing and invertible. What does the solution look like? It must be something in terms of the inverted function $U$ I'm guessing, but I can't get the expression without a specific functional form.
I know that in general you get something like
$$ MRS = p_j / p_k $$
but I'm looking for a characterization in terms of something like
$$ q_1 = g\Big(y,p_1,p_2\Big) $$

Dont you need stronger condition to ensure existence of the function g? what about perfect substitutes?

There is no continuous invertible function whose domain includes an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$.

I do not know what invertibility of $U$ means as $U$ is a real valued function of two variables.
The following is true however:

If $U$ is continuous, then Berge's extreme value theorem tells us that a solution exists. This solution can be a correspondence of $(p,y)$ (multivalued) but it will be upper-hemicontinuous.
If in addition $U$ is strictly concave, then for any $(p,y)$ there is a  solution must be unique. To see this, assume the optimal solution is not unique. Then take two of them. By strict (quasi) concavity, the convex combination of these two bundles gives strictly higher utility. As the budget is linear, it is also feasible. But this contradicted the optimality of the two initial bundles.
As such, if $U$ is continuous and strictly (quasi)-concave, one can write $q_1(y, p_1, p_2)$ and $q_2(y,p_1, p_2)$ as the unique demand functions. From upper hemi-contiuity in the first bullet point, it follows that both of them will be continuous.

In general it is not possible to get an expression for $q_1$ and $q_2$ without imposing a functional form on $U$.

Well you already have an answer in your question. Without any specific functional form for utility the the general solution is;
$$q_i^*=q_i(p_1,p_2,y), \quad \text{for } i=1,2$$
Where $q_i$ are chosen such that the following conditions and budget constraint are satisfied;
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}-p_i \lambda = 0$$
